# NSHttpCookie getting cookies in case of iOS version 10

Tags: xamarin, cookies, xamarin.ios, uiwebview, webclient

I want to implement download pdf document feature using WebClient in Xamain iOS. Currently its working perfect for iOS 11, where I am getting cookies using HttpCookieStore.
For iOS 10, I could not able to retrieve cookies.

Flow to work on this is 1. Getting cookies 2.Creating webclient server request with cookies added into header.

for iOS 11, 
Following is the syntax to get cookies :

```
NSHttpCookie[] cookieStoreData;

    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
            {
                var cookieStore = webView.Configuration.WebsiteDataStore.HttpCookieStore;
                cookieStoreData = await cookieStore.GetAllCookiesAsync();
            }
```

For iOS 10,

```
cookieStoreData = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.Cookies;
```

It does not return any cookies in these scenario so next call of webclient to server gets fail (In case of iOS 10).

```
StringBuilder cookies = new StringBuilder();
var webClient = new WebClient ();

foreach (var temp in cookieStoreData)
{
  cookies.Append(temp.Name + "=" + temp.Value + ";");
}  

webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookies.ToString()); 



webClient.DownloadDataAsync (webView.Url);
webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) => {
if (e.Error == null)
{
    // Downloading data......
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("URL for page : " + e.Error.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine("URL for page : " + e.Error);
    new UIAlertView("Done", "Download Failed. Please try again.", null, "OK", null).Show();
}
```

Comment: Where did you want to get the cookies?In UIWebview,WKWebview or some URL request such as AFNetworking?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT It's WKWebView. Now i can retrieve cookies using decide policy method but I could not get complete list of cookies comparing to HttpCookieStore

Comment: Getting cookies : [Export("webView:decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:decisionHandler:")]
  public void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationResponse navigationResponse, Action<WKNavigationResponsePolicy> decisionHandler) {

   NSHttpUrlResponse response;

            response = (NSHttpUrlResponse)navigationResponse.Response;

            cookies_holder = NSHttpCookie.CookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(response.AllHeaderFields, webView.Url);
   decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicy.Allow);
  }

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

1. NSHTTPCookieStorage isn’t reliable because WKWebView does all of its
   networking in a separate process, so you can’t get at the
   NSHTTPCookieStorage object being used by the web view.
2. JavaScript (like the WKUserScript 
   ) doesn’t
   see any cookies tagged with HttpOnly.
3. WKWebsiteDataStore lets you know of the existence of the cookie but
   doesn’t let you get the contents.
4. The delegate approach you showed  won’t see all the cookies because
   not all responses are navigation responses.

**Solution:**
The best solution is using `UIWebview` instead of  `WKWebView`.For more detail you can access [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/77279) .

Comment: I saw you asked a similar question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53172888/how-to-get-webview-cookies-in-ios-10 .You can delete it if my answer is useful

Comment: will update on this post after some analysis. Thanks again for your answers !

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT, UIWebview is dead. We can't publish our app since Apple's announcement. Is there a solution that you know for Wkwebview nowadays?

Comment: @Erdogan i have face same problem. if you have any solution then please help me.

Comment: @YogendraPatel yes. If you use a specific website, you know which cookies are using. I set them in the OnElementChanged, it's a cheat way but works. 

NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.AcceptPolicy = NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicy.Always;
NSHttpCookie cook1 = new NSHttpCookie("JSESSIONPR", "/VROnline", "www...com");
SHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.SetCookie(cook1);

you can add too many cookies at the same time. Hope this helps you.